# pulling webpages from an adult site -- how to get past the site agreement?

Tags: html, ruby, parsing

I'm trying to parse a bunch of webpages from an adult website using Ruby:

```
require 'hpricot'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Hpricot(open('random page on an adult website'))
```

However, what I end up getting instead is that initial 'Site Agreement' page making sure that you're 18+, etc.

How do I get past the Site Agreement and pull the webpages I want? (If there's a way to do it, any language is fine.)

Comment: be aware that bypassing the TOS for a site like this may well be illegal in your jurisdiction, and that many gallery sites take an extremely dim view of automated scraping.

Comment: @Josh: isn't that exactly what he's trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to figure out how the site detects that a visitor has accepted the agreement.

The most obvious choice would be cookies.  Likely when a visitor accepts the agreement, a cookie is sent to their browser, which is then passed back to the site on every subsequent request.

You'll have to get your script to act like a visitor by accepting the cookie, and sending it with every subsequent request.  This will require programming on your part to request the "accept agreement" page first, find the cookie, and store it for use.  It's likely that they don't use a specific cookie for the agreement, but rather store it in a session, in which case you just need to find the session cookie.

Answer (score 0):

The 'Site Agreement' page probably has a link you have to click or form you have to submit to send back to the server to proceed. Read the source of that page to be sure. You could send that response back from your application. I don't know how to do that in Ruby, but I've seen similar tasks done using cURL and libcurl, which can probably be used from Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Install LiveHTTPHeaders plugin for Firefox and visit this site. Watch the headers and see what happens when you accept the agreement. You'll probably see that the browser sends some request (possibly a Post) and accepts some cookies. Then you'll have to repeat whatever browser does in your Ruby script.