# How to get all webpages on a domain

Tags: php, dns, subdomain, web-crawler

I am making a simple *web spider* and I was wondering if there is a way that can be triggered in my PHP code that I can get all the webpages on a domain...

e.g Lets say I wanted to get all the webpages on Stackoverflow.com . That means that it would get:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
[pulling webpages from an adult site -- how to get past the site agreement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903214/)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234214/
[Best Rails HTML Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395261/best-rails-html-parser?rq=1)

And all the links. How can I get that. Or is there an **API** or **DIRECTORY** that can enable me to get that?

Also is there a way I can get all the **subdomains**?

Btw how do crawlers crawl websites that don't have [SiteMaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) or [Syndication feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syndication_feed)?

Cheers.

Comment: What you are asking for is a major security breach portable to all web domains. There might exist one, but I hope you don't find it!

Comment: Hahaha...I had no idea. Then how does Google Index webpages if there exists no such thing?

Comment: As you might have noticed, there are LOTS of pages, that are not in the Google index. Basically, if a page is in the google index, there is a link to it. No link, no search engine. In many use cases, this link comes from the site itself and is provided exactly for that purpouse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a site wants you to be able to do this, they will probably provide a [Sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps). Using a combination of a sitemap and following the links on pages, you should be able to traverse all the pages on a site - but this is really up to the owner of the site, and how accessible they make it.

If the site does *not* want you to do this, there is nothing you can do to work around it. HTTP does not provide any standard mechanism for listing the contents of a directory.

Comment: Sitemaps were introduced in 2005...how did Google and Yahoo index sites before then?

Comment: @WilliamTheDev By following links on pages (looking at `href` attributes etc). A lot of this is down to the site - if you don't provide a sitemap and you don't provide a good navigation mechanism for your site, you won't get good Google coverage either.

Comment: Ah...Okay. So they start from index.php and hope that the links on the index page will lead to others that will lead to others and hopefully hey can cover the whole site. Got it.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev NB: Don't start at index.php, start at `/` - not every site has an "index.php" (StackOverflow being an example of one that doesn't). Also, *start with sitemap.xml* (if available), to get a list of your base pages, *then* crawl those pages to traverse the rest of your site. What you have come across here is sort of the whole point of SEO (in as much as there is any point). SEO is really just making the site navigable by a robot.

Comment: Sitemap.xml ...I did not know of that one. Just noticed that many sites have it. Nice.

So like file_get_contents($url) while $url is the familiar ones like index.php, index.html, default.php, default.html ... Thanks mate.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev Like I say (in the absence of a sitemap) start at `/` (as in `http://www.domain.com/`) rather than appending random file names. `/` means "the default page for the site" - well, actually it means "the root directory", but 99.999% of sites will either serve you a page from this URL or will redirect you to the default page.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev Also, if you are going to get into this sort of thing, I highly recommend you acquaint yourself with [this document](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html). It's a bit dry I admit, but it is the single most useful document on the internet for a web developer IMHO.

Comment: Its true...it is dry. But it has a lot of useful info. Cheers bro!

Comment: By the way, how does Google index pages that are dynamic?

Something like this `website.com/index.php?id=2&p=1`

Do they have to be listed in the sitemap too for Google to index or does Google do an intelligent filling or bruteforce where it inserts possible values of p and id?

Comment: @WilliamTheDev Again, just by following links. They don't invent values for parameters, that wouldn't do anyone any good. But in the example URL you give there, I imagine `id` is some product ID or something, and there will be a link to it from the main page. And `p` is presumably page no, so you should be able to get to `p=2` by following the page nav links on the page. Anything that is not reachable just by following links from the main page should go in the sitemap. All of this is down to the site owner - this is what SEO is almost entirely based on.

Comment: So in short Google can't crawl search. Something like website.com/index.php?search=productfirstname+productsecondname

Comment: @WilliamTheDev It *could* but it doesn't, because if you think about it it would just end up "searching" stuff up forever, because it doesn't know what the site is about, it just knows it's a set of pages. Whenever you find Google linking you to a set of search results on a site, it's because some page somewhere linked to that specific set of search results.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to hack the server sorry.

What you can do is that, if you own the domain [www.my-domain.com](http://www.my-domain.com), you can put a PHP file there, that you use as a request on demand file.  That php file you will need to code some sort of code in that can look at the Folders FTP Wise.  PHP can connect to a FTP server, so thats a way to go :)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

You can with PHP read the dirs folders and return that as an array.  Best i can do.

Answer (score 1):

As you have said, you must follow all the links.

To do this, you must start by retrieving stackoverflow.com, easy: `file_get_contents ("http:\\stackoverflow.com")`.

Then parse its contents, looking for links: `<a href="question/ask">`, not so easy.

You store those new URL's in a database and then parse that those after, which will give you a whole new set of URL's, parse those. Soon enough you'll have the vast majority of the site's content, including stuff like sub1.stackoverflow.com. This is called crawling, and it is quite simple to implement, although not so simple to retrieve useful information once you have all that data.

If you are only interested in one particular domain, be sure to dismiss links to external sites.

Answer (score 0):

No, not the way you are asking.

However, provided you have a clear goal in mind, you may be able to:

- use a "primary" request to get the objects of interest. Some sites provide JSON, XML, ... apis to list such objects (e.g SO can list questions this way). Then use "per-object" requests to fetch information specific to one object
- fetch information from other open (or paid) sources, e.g. search engines, directories, "forensic" tools such as SpyOnWeb
- reverse engineer the structure of the site, e.g. you know that `/item/<id>` gets you to the page of item whose ID is `<id>`
- ask the webmaster

Please note that some of these solutions may be in violation of the site's termes of use. Anyway these are just pointers, on top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WinHTTPTack](http://www.httrack.com)/. But it is a polite not to hammer other peoples web sites.

I just use it to find broken links and make a snap shot.

If you do start hammering other peoples sites they will take measures. Some of them will not be nice (i.e. hammer yours).

Just be polite.

Comment: Nah...I'm not trying to save local copies for offline browsing mate, I am thinking of how to make a web spider.

Comment: And their site appears to be down.

Comment: @WilliamTheDev - It is working for me. The OP is effectively fetching a local copy. Perhaps throw it away when you are done it. Google grabs a page on its machine. Does the business and then chucks it away.