# How to use LinkExtractor to get all urls in a website?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I wonder if there is a way to get all urls in the entire website. It seems that Scrapy with CrawSpider and LinkExtractor is a good choice. Consider this example:

```
from scrapy.item import Field, Item
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class SampleItem(Item):
    link = Field()


class SampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "sample_spider"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://domain.com"]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_page', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_page(self, response):
        item = SampleItem()
        item['link'] = response.url
        return item
```

This spider does not give me what I want. It only gives me all the links on a single webpage, namely, the start_url. But what I want is every link in this website, including those that are not on the start url. Did I understand the example correctly? Is there a solution to my problem? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could create a spider that gathers all the links in a page then for each of those links, check for the domain : if it is the same, parse those links, rinse , repeat.

There's no guarantee however that you'll catch all pages of the said domain, see [How to get all webpages on a domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13922335/how-to-get-all-webpages-on-a-domain) for a good overview of the issue in my opinion.

```
class SampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "sample_spider"
allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
start_urls = ["http://domain.com"]


def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    urls = hxs.select('//a/@href').extract()

    # make sure the parsed url is the domain related.
    for u in urls:
        # print('response url:{} | link url: {}'.format(response.url, u))
        if urlsplit(u).netloc == urlsplit(response.url).netloc:
            yield scrapy.Request(u, self.parse)
```

Answer (score 2):

Export each item via a [Feed Export](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-exports).  This will result in a list of all links found on the site.

Or, write your own [Item Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) to export all of your links to a file, database, or whatever you choose.

Another option would be to create a spider level list to which you append each URL, instead of using items at all.  How you proceed will really depend on what you need from the spider, and how you intend to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Rejected. But I'm not sure if my question is clear enough. In fact, exporting the urls isn't a problem. The problem is that the the example above only gives me all the urls on the start-url webpage, such as [link](http://domain.com/xxx, or http://domain.com/yyy), but what I need is all urls in the entire website, including urls such as [link](http://domain.com/xxx/zzz), which are not directly accessible from the start url page. Can Scrapy do it?

Comment: Yes. Read the links and suggestions I provided.  An item pipeline could compile all of the links that come through it into a single list.  A spider level list would also work.  Are there reasons these two options don't work?